# Ant; how to specify a file is executable so I don't have to chmod+x each time

Tags: ant, build, executable

When build my application with Ant, it produces a ZIP file.

I have a `sh` file inside this zip, that is included as part of the build process. After each build I have to do `chmod +x myFile.sh` as ant fails to retain its original executable permissions.

How can I instruct ant to keep executable permissions to this file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this with the `filemode` attribute:

```
<zip destfile="myapp.zip">
    <zipfileset dir="scripts" includes="myscript.sh" filemode="755" />
    <zipfileset dir="build" includes="myapp.jar" />
</zip>
```